# Is there an way to read my mysql database with gorm in Go?

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

I was writing query to access my database named k_movies by gorm but everytime when i run it throw an error.

```
kumardivyanshu@Divyanshus-MacBook-Air ~/myproject/src/github.com/gorm_mysql % go run test.go

(/Users/kumardivyanshu/myproject/src/github.com/gorm_mysql/test.go:36) 
[2021-05-12 10:02:47]  Error 1054: Unknown column 'k_movies.deleted_at' in 'where clause' 

(/Users/kumardivyanshu/myproject/src/github.com/gorm_mysql/test.go:36) 
[2021-05-12 10:02:47]  [10.89ms]  SELECT * FROM `k_movies`  WHERE `k_movies`.`deleted_at` IS NULL  
[0 rows affected or returned ] 
2021/05/12 10:02:47 Error 1054: Unknown column 'k_movies.deleted_at' in 'where clause'
exit status 1
```

I didnt used any query to check the deleted at but i dont know why its coming i refers to gorm doc but didnt came with the solution, can anyone help me in this.

Below is the code which I wrote.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
    _ "github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/mysql"
)

type k_movie struct {
    gorm.Model
    title string `gorm:"not null;unique"`
}

func openDB() *gorm.DB {
    user := "root"
    password := "123@wqe"
    database := "dbdump"

    mysqlURL := "%s:%s@/%s?charset=utf8mb4&parseTime=True&loc=Local"

    db, err := gorm.Open("mysql", fmt.Sprintf(mysqlURL, user, password, database))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    return db
}

func main() {
    db := openDB()
    db.LogMode(true)
    // initDB(db)

    records := db.Find(&k_movie{})
    if records.Error != nil {
        log.Fatalln(records.Error)
    }

    log.Printf("%d rows found.", records.RowsAffected)
    rows, err := records.Rows()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    defer rows.Close()

    for rows.Next() {
        var group k_movie
        err := db.ScanRows(rows, &group)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalln(err)
        }

        log.Printf("%+v\n", group)
    }
    if rows.Err() != nil {
        log.Fatalln(rows.Err())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is what's happening:
Your model is based on [gorm.Model](https://gorm.io/docs/models.html#gorm-Model), which by default includes the `deletedAt` field, to allow you to *soft delete* rows (this means the row is not really deleted, but a timestamp is added in that `deletedAt` column).
Then, every query includes `deletedAt = NULL` to only get the rows not deleted.

Check out the docs here for more info and examples: https://gorm.io/docs/delete.html#Soft-Delete

You can just add the column to your table if you find soft deletions a good thing for your service, or remove the `deletedAt` attribute to your model by not using the default `gorm.Model` to implement it.

Comment: and if i remove gorm.model its just print title

Comment: right, you will need to add the remaining fields manually, or add the `deletedAt` column to the table

Comment: no no it just printing this `title` but in mysql database i have 100+ entries in the field `title`

Comment: oh it prints the column name instead of the content of the rows?